# Как мне сделать словарь из значений в json файле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, файлы, словари

У меня есть `json` файл который выглядит вот так:

```
{"8ac1590e97dd2d541eba44eb3bcd0eb15e9b9227": {"score": 0.00016706838505342603, "start": 221, "end": 272, "answer": "типовым проектам жилых и общественных зданий, город"}, "1deeaf4e32ca8c547e802eb8ce5b99f252d2645a": {"score": 0.00013428617967292666, "start": 7, "end": 89, "answer": "м годам жилищное строительство распространилось на район восточнее Батарейной горы"}, "f1f9b0b058e2dfdb2eebf165d3cb27bd250db684": {"score": 0.00016324518946930766, "start": 74, "end": 89, "answer": "Батарейной горы"}, "1a6108412c10916226599c853668a2cb37351d31": {"score": 0.00016644333663862199, "start": 74, "end": 89, "answer": "Батарейной горы"}, "59d328a25568dec9042cf2da603e576f383f6268": {"score": 0.00015193452418316156, "start": 221, "end": 228, "answer": "типовым"}, "ce7158743b30ee81d4a96ea11492e58ea151c0a1": {"score": 0.00015055813128128648, "start": 221, "end": 228, "answer": "типовым"}, "3867c985e2d712aee76630ebce6edadd8e9ffa55": {"score": 0.00014423212269321084, "start": 221, "end": 228, "answer": "типовым"}, "a6c32f5a67aa3871487d828e8c65a9cc000f4f8d": {"score": 0.0001486447872593999, "start": 356, "end": 412, "answer": "Меняется структура транспорта: на смену закрытому в 1957"}, "7adbb4281fa541840b4bf53cd5ce951da13e1e20": {"score": 0.0001673035731073469, "start": 221, "end": 228, "answer": "типовым"}, "f6c9fb66d4b9f4603429638ab84edc675cca375c": {"score": 0.00039533377275802195, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "a464dbb9d2cf7b689801bb1849659435b5edd173": {"score": 0.00041943788528442383, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "3e357e4e69951610a0a4c937463e6cc08f96e804": {"score": 0.0004219314723741263, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "7a2a924a9cdcc619615e4f8a9c6aae40aab1034f": {"score": 0.000482065457617864, "start": 215, "end": 287, "answer": "культурах придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "ba392369009c92fd33be6739cd44ab926922cbc0": {"score": 0.0004400738107506186, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "69dbb709282322b366eab4f9d4c6d9d216afb0bd": {"score": 0.0004379094752948731, "start": 215, "end": 287, "answer": "культурах придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "eafbd5d671e218a64a505c173b9037a0b1d19a69": {"score": 0.0004758248687721789, "start": 215, "end": 287, "answer": "культурах придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "dfb527a9939c7bb8606bc562e0c925869aac14e8": {"score": 0.0004367684596218169, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "a848e84106e18c5c8ebc2b8031e9343934d35d00": {"score": 0.00044802590855397284, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "7b719e5f48709a669eeb0f6efa4ca00616502e69": {"score": 0.0004383519699331373, "start": 215, "end": 287, "answer": "культурах придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "dac3d01634efa8472ece43e7c63efc14c41b2d1c": {"score": 0.0004525718977674842, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "cc55d64b7175e37ab45e6b54edac71951cea00fd": {"score": 0.0004511384468059987, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "b9d8470cb27da5e6ae11931d9b0902d3bcd504c4": {"score": 0.0002014314814005047, "start": 1405, "end": 1432, "answer": "в дни мятежа Нерва усыновил"},
```

Как оттуда взять все id ответов и значения в answer и записать в json файл?

Мне надо оттуда взять все id (пример: 8ac1590e97dd2d541eba44eb3bcd0eb15e9b9227) и ответы которые в answer. Должен получиться вот такой json файл:

```
{
    "8ac1590e97dd2d541eba44eb3bcd0eb15e9b9227": "была разрушена в ходе войны",
    "1deeaf4e32ca8c547e802eb8ce5b99f252d2645a": "часть которых была разрушена в ходе войны",
    "f1f9b0b058e2dfdb2eebf165d3cb27bd250db684": "горы",
    "1a6108412c10916226599c853668a2cb37351d31": "экономики",
    "59d328a25568dec9042cf2da603e576f383f6268": "ходе войны",
    "ce7158743b30ee81d4a96ea11492e58ea151c0a1": "населения Выборга достигла 65 тыс",
    "3867c985e2d712aee76630ebce6edadd8e9ffa55": "в ходе войны",
    "a6c32f5a67aa3871487d828e8c65a9cc000f4f8d": "паровозы с 1969 года вытесняются электропоездами",
    "7adbb4281fa541840b4bf53cd5ce951da13e1e20": "работу только в 1968 году",
    "f6c9fb66d4b9f4603429638ab84edc675cca375c": "во многих контекстах понятие мужчина обозначает прежде всего социальную группу",
    "a464dbb9d2cf7b689801bb1849659435b5edd173": "исследователи",
    "3e357e4e69951610a0a4c937463e6cc08f96e804": "жёсткое соответствие приписанного человеку при рождении пола и гендерной роли",
    "7a2a924a9cdcc619615e4f8a9c6aae40aab1034f": "соответствие приписанного человеку при рождении",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d = {"8ac1590e97dd2d541eba44eb3bcd0eb15e9b9227": {"score": 0.00016706838505342603, "start": 221, "end": 272, "answer": "типовым проектам жилых и общественных зданий, город"}, "1deeaf4e32ca8c547e802eb8ce5b99f252d2645a": {"score": 0.00013428617967292666, "start": 7, "end": 89, "answer": "м годам жилищное строительство распространилось на район восточнее Батарейной горы"}, "f1f9b0b058e2dfdb2eebf165d3cb27bd250db684": {"score": 0.00016324518946930766, "start": 74, "end": 89, "answer": "Батарейной горы"}, "1a6108412c10916226599c853668a2cb37351d31": {"score": 0.00016644333663862199, "start": 74, "end": 89, "answer": "Батарейной горы"}, "59d328a25568dec9042cf2da603e576f383f6268": {"score": 0.00015193452418316156, "start": 221, "end": 228, "answer": "типовым"}, "ce7158743b30ee81d4a96ea11492e58ea151c0a1": {"score": 0.00015055813128128648, "start": 221, "end": 228, "answer": "типовым"}, "3867c985e2d712aee76630ebce6edadd8e9ffa55": {"score": 0.00014423212269321084, "start": 221, "end": 228, "answer": "типовым"}, "a6c32f5a67aa3871487d828e8c65a9cc000f4f8d": {"score": 0.0001486447872593999, "start": 356, "end": 412, "answer": "Меняется структура транспорта: на смену закрытому в 1957"}, "7adbb4281fa541840b4bf53cd5ce951da13e1e20": {"score": 0.0001673035731073469, "start": 221, "end": 228, "answer": "типовым"}, "f6c9fb66d4b9f4603429638ab84edc675cca375c": {"score": 0.00039533377275802195, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "a464dbb9d2cf7b689801bb1849659435b5edd173": {"score": 0.00041943788528442383, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "3e357e4e69951610a0a4c937463e6cc08f96e804": {"score": 0.0004219314723741263, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "7a2a924a9cdcc619615e4f8a9c6aae40aab1034f": {"score": 0.000482065457617864, "start": 215, "end": 287, "answer": "культурах придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "ba392369009c92fd33be6739cd44ab926922cbc0": {"score": 0.0004400738107506186, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "69dbb709282322b366eab4f9d4c6d9d216afb0bd": {"score": 0.0004379094752948731, "start": 215, "end": 287, "answer": "культурах придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "eafbd5d671e218a64a505c173b9037a0b1d19a69": {"score": 0.0004758248687721789, "start": 215, "end": 287, "answer": "культурах придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "dfb527a9939c7bb8606bc562e0c925869aac14e8": {"score": 0.0004367684596218169, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "a848e84106e18c5c8ebc2b8031e9343934d35d00": {"score": 0.00044802590855397284, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "7b719e5f48709a669eeb0f6efa4ca00616502e69": {"score": 0.0004383519699331373, "start": 215, "end": 287, "answer": "культурах придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "dac3d01634efa8472ece43e7c63efc14c41b2d1c": {"score": 0.0004525718977674842, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "cc55d64b7175e37ab45e6b54edac71951cea00fd": {"score": 0.0004511384468059987, "start": 225, "end": 287, "answer": "придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина"}, "b9d8470cb27da5e6ae11931d9b0902d3bcd504c4": {"score": 0.0002014314814005047, "start": 1405, "end": 1432, "answer": "в дни мятежа Нерва усыновил"}}
```

Обходом словаря:

```
new_d = dict()
    for i in d:
        new_d[i] = d[i]['answer']
```

Результат в `new_d`:

```
>>> new_d
{'8ac1590e97dd2d541eba44eb3bcd0eb15e9b9227': 'типовым проектам жилых и общественных зданий, город', '1deeaf4e32ca8c547e802eb8ce5b99f252d2645a': 'м годам жилищное строительство распространилось на район восточнее Батарейной горы', 'f1f9b0b058e2dfdb2eebf165d3cb27bd250db684': 'Батарейной горы', '1a6108412c10916226599c853668a2cb37351d31': 'Батарейной горы', '59d328a25568dec9042cf2da603e576f383f6268': 'типовым', 'ce7158743b30ee81d4a96ea11492e58ea151c0a1': 'типовым', '3867c985e2d712aee76630ebce6edadd8e9ffa55': 'типовым', 'a6c32f5a67aa3871487d828e8c65a9cc000f4f8d': 'Меняется структура транспорта: на смену закрытому в 1957', '7adbb4281fa541840b4bf53cd5ce951da13e1e20': 'типовым', 'f6c9fb66d4b9f4603429638ab84edc675cca375c': 'придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина', 'a464dbb9d2cf7b689801bb1849659435b5edd173': 'придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина', '3e357e4e69951610a0a4c937463e6cc08f96e804': 'придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина', '7a2a924a9cdcc619615e4f8a9c6aae40aab1034f': 'культурах придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина', 'ba392369009c92fd33be6739cd44ab926922cbc0': 'придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина', '69dbb709282322b366eab4f9d4c6d9d216afb0bd': 'культурах придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина', 'eafbd5d671e218a64a505c173b9037a0b1d19a69': 'культурах придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина', 'dfb527a9939c7bb8606bc562e0c925869aac14e8': 'придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина', 'a848e84106e18c5c8ebc2b8031e9343934d35d00': 'придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина', '7b719e5f48709a669eeb0f6efa4ca00616502e69': 'культурах придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина', 'dac3d01634efa8472ece43e7c63efc14c41b2d1c': 'придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина', 'cc55d64b7175e37ab45e6b54edac71951cea00fd': 'придаётся природе. Однако во многих контекстах понятие мужчина', 'b9d8470cb27da5e6ae11931d9b0902d3bcd504c4': 'в дни мятежа Нерва усыновил'}
```

или через dict comprehension (компактнее):

```
new_d = {i: d[i]['answer'] for i in d}
```

будет тот же результат в `new_d`, и запись в файл `.json`:

```
import json

with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(new_d, fp)
```

Comment: только d у меня это json файл  который я открываю так sample = json.load(open('/content/sabmit.json', 'r')) Сработает если по нему проходиться циклом?